# Past 7 days running amounts average as progress per each date

Tags: sql, oracle

So, the query is simple but i am facing issues in implementing the Sql logic. Heres the query suppose i have records like

```
  Phoneno Company Date      Amount 
   83838   xyz    20210901  100
   87337   abc    20210902  500
   47473   cde    20210903  600
```

Output expected is past 7 days progress as running avg of amount for each date (current date n 6 days before)

```
   Date         amount avg
   20210901     100    100
   20210902     500    300
   20210903     600    400
```

I tried

```
  Select date, amount, select 
  avg(lg) from (
  Select case when lag(amount)
  Over (order by NULL) IS NULL
  THEN AMOUNT
  ELSE
  lag(amount)
  Over (order by NULL) END AS LG) 
  From table
  WHERE DATE>=t.date-7) as avg
  From table t;
```

But i am getting wrong avg values. Could anyone please help?

Note: Ive tried without lag too it results the wrong avgs too

Comment: either is mysql or is oracle, but not both.

Comment: Tag only the database that you use.

Comment: Added the database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a self `join` to group the dates

```
select distinct 
       a.dt,
       b.dt as preceding_dt, --just for QA purpose
       a.amt,
       b.amt as preceding_amt,--just for QA purpose
       avg(b.amt) over (partition by a.dt) as avg_amt
from t a
join t b on  a.dt-b.dt between 0 and 6
group by a.dt, b.dt, a.amt, b.amt; --to dedupe the data after the join
```

If you want to make your `correlated subquery` approach work, you don't really need the `lag`.

```
select dt, 
       amt, 
      (select avg(b.amt) from t b where a.dt-b.dt between 0 and 6) as avg_lg
from t a;
```

If you don't have multiple rows per date, this gets even simpler

```
select dt, 
       amt, 
      avg(amt) over (order by dt rows between 6 preceding and current row) as avg_lg
 from t;
```

Also the condition `DATE>=t.date-7` you used is left open on one side meaning it will qualify a lot of dates that shouldn't have been qualified.

[**DEMO**](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/jkV2ETVgQCjgzGLd49wm8/3)

Comment: Appreciate the effort also, i wanna know why it din work in my query

Comment: @HimanshuAhuja Hopefully my edit helps

Comment: Great man! Thats what i was doing idk what i was thinking when i was using the same query messed up in the where clause i guess

Answer (score 1):

You can use analytical function with the windowing clause to get your results:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT BillingDate, 
       AVG(amount) OVER (ORDER BY BillingDate 
                         RANGE BETWEEN TO_DSINTERVAL('7 00:00:00') PRECEDING 
                               AND TO_DSINTERVAL('0 00:00:00') FOLLOWING) AS RUNNING_AVG
FROM accounts
ORDER BY BillingDate;
```

Here is a DBFiddle showing the query in action ([LINK](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=3ec77dc95fd473b29e8378ab01d11256))